# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `Projectname`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

```php
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I run the `php artisan migrate` only the users table gets created then the migration process stops...

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `Projectname`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint
> `users_project_id_foreign` foreign key (`project_id`) references
> `projects` (`id`))

Comment: Would help me to see the actual SQL. Otherwise up to the laravel folks.

Comment: I gave you an answer with description,  if it help then mark that answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up your **migration** directory, you will see all your migration files, like *2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table*

> You are getting this error because your **projects_create_table** should be migrate before **create_users_table** file.

By default, laravel makes every migration file name by a `date_time` format, like `2014_10_12_000000_table_names.php` So that, all files can be migrate serialwise. 
So change your **create_users_table** file name with a `date_time`, so that can be migrate after **projects_create_table**, like :

```
2020_01_01_000000_create_projects_table.php
2020_01_01_000001_create_users_table.php
```

Now, if you run `php artisan migrate`,  at first `projects` table will be created, then `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

You used `constrained()` which tends to find table `project` or `user` Not `projects` or `users`. In that case you need to specify table name in `constrained()`.

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained('projects');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You can study more from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)